# How do I pass the list of drag and dropped files to the install4J launcher?

Tags: macos, install4j

I have an install4J Launcher with a macOS Info.plist fragment that has CFBundleTypeExtensions and UTExportedTypeDeclarations to enable drag-and-drop of files onto the generated Mac app. That's all well and good starting the app from the desktop, but how do I pass the list of dropped files to the underlying JVM and java app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file names can be retrieved by registering a startup listener:

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/#install4j.api.singleInstance

This also works if you double click a document in the finder that has a file association with the launcher.